# Android Maps- Compare two directions for similarity

Tags: android, algorithm, google-maps-api-3, gps, maps

I have two arrays of GPS locations obtained while traveling from location A to location B. The starting and ending point of the two arrays is same.

I want to calculate if the two arrays correspond to the same path traversed or not?

Best Regards

Comment: I have no idea what to do. I am considering the option to compare two polylines for similarity...

Comment: @MogamboKhushHua What accuracy do you require for comparison?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use the [Hausdorff Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance), it calculates a metric of similarity between two point clouds(arrays).

Comment: +1. Hausdorff would make really neat solution as it could be made tolerant to minor differences between the paths, and different sampling points, and different array lengths and ... .

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [Fréchet distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance) for this task. It suits perfectly in my opinion.